# How is it traditionally defined the minimum wage legislation in economics?

Tags: labor-economics, minimum-wage

How is it traditionally defined the minimum wage legislation in economics? And which countries does not have a minimum wage legislation as defined in these terms?

Comment: Welcome to Econ.SE! What do you by "defined"? Are you referring to how it is stated in the legislation? The wording?

Comment: What can be considered a minimum wage policy for economics, because some countries talk about minimum per hour, or monthly, and there might be other differences. I am also interested to know if there is a country with no definition and legislation regarding minimum wage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Some countries use hourly wage (Australia, Morocco, UK, US), other use daily (Mexico), other monthly (Argentina, Brazil, Chile, Colombia, France, Peru, Spain), others annually (Bolivia). (*this is not an exhaustive list*)

Countries without a minimum wage **established by law** are: Denmark, Iceland, Italy, Norway, Sweden, Switzerland. They do however have minimum wages negotiated at the trade union level, even at industry level.

Given this information, the "traditionally" adjective you are using is not very helpful.